# Rebuilding link database in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

I am getting the below error while rebuilding link database in Sitecore 8.1 (Initial release).

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.RebuildLinkDatabase.RebuildLinkDatabaseForm.CheckStatus()

any suggestion to fix the error?

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Would be great if Sitecore adding some basic logging on this. Kind of difficult if you have hundreds of thousands of items in your content tree!

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore 8.1 was released over 5 years ago, tons of improvements were made since then. Product seem to be [out of mainstream support](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/641167), hence Sitecore would not assist you here.

You could do following:

1. Download [iLSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases) - reverse engineering tool to see the source code
2. Inspect how `RebuildLinkDatabaseForm` class, `CheckStatus` method is implemented; where NRE could bubble up
3. Recompile code with either additional logging & improved NRE handling & wire it up via `wwwroot\sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\RebuildLinkDatabase\RebuildLinkDatabase.xml` file